# Confused about "Adding Comments"

Tags: support, comments

Over in [This Thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/are-there-any-systems-that-are-specifically-designed-for-online-real-time-text-pl) I posted a response that really should have been a comment.  However I don't see the option to add a comment to the question.  In fact the only place I have the ability to add comments is to my own posts.

Am I missing something obvious here?  Feel free to slap me if I've made an obvious user error ;)

Comment: You know you could always ask a question or four?  People seem to vote those up ... just saying.

Answer (score 7):

You need 50 reputation to comment on other peoples posts.

Check out the [FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) for what various levels of reputation will allow you to do.

Comment: In that case I would suggest that restricting comments is detrimental to the clarity of the thread and should be a base function.  But thanks, I hadn't realised that ;)

Comment: @Jagged - I agree that it is frustrating.  I assume that it slows down spammers some so I do see the utility.  Fortunately, it will only affect you once on all stackexchange sites total.  Assuming you link your logins together you'll start with +100 rep on the second site.

Comment: Also, you can check http://rpg.stackexchange.com/privileges to see what permissions your current reputation has earned you.